# Calculate frequency distribution of array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am required to write a program that reads data into an array of type int. Valid values are from 0 to 10. your program should determine how many values were input. ***Output a list of distinct entries and a count of how many times that entry occurred***."

I'm having trouble with the bolded part, this is what i have so far...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("How many scores will you enter?");

    int total = 0;
    string inValue;
    string Size = Console.ReadLine();
    int arraySize = Convert.ToInt32(Size);
    int [] ScoreArray = new int [arraySize];

    for (int i = 0; i < ScoreArray.Length; i++)
    {

        Console.Write("Enter a Number between 0 and 10, #{0}: ", i + 1);
        inValue = Console.ReadLine();
        ScoreArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(inValue);

        total += ScoreArray[i];
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Number of scores entered: " + arraySize);
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: store the entries into a map with the key being the distinct value and the value being the number of times you have encountered that key.

Comment: What have you tried? In any case, consider this: `ScoreArray[theNumber] += 1` instead of `ScoreArray[i] = ...`; what difference would this make?

Comment: @pst what do you understand from `this is what i have so far`

Comment: @L.B. What I don't understand is *how* that dealt with the **bold part** ...

Comment: This will likely be closed because you don't actually have a real question. What is it specifically that you are having trouble with, what don't you understand, what have you tried? Right now your question is just open ended to "Provide me the code to the part I don't understand."

Comment: Sorry I wasnt very specific.
What I dont understand is how I make it display only the distinct numbers (from what I undersand that means no doubles). Nor do I know how to count each time each number was used. I know this is really just a refrase of the statement above and I understand your dilema, by no means do I want you to just give me the answere. but if you could point me in the right direction I would be gratefull.

Comment: @JoeFredy - I've added some more details to my answer.  I think that should get you started at the very least.  I usually don't add real code for homework questions, but I guess I felt generous today.

Comment: pst gave you the solution in the nice hint. :-)

Comment: @All, Thank you all for the timely and very helpfull hints, information, and suport. Great forum community here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key here is **valid values are between 0-10**.  I would use the array index to store each value itself.  For example, if you process the value 5, increment `values[5]`.

So first you'd initialize an array like:

```
int[] values = new int[11]; //Values 0-10
```

Then, loop until the user just enters *blank*:

```
while(true)
{
   string inValue = Console.ReadLine();
   if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(inValue)) break;

   values[Convert.ToInt32(inValue)]++; //Bounds checking would be nice here
}
```

You can then display a sorted distinct list by looping through the array once and printing out any index with a value greater than 0:

```
for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
   if(values[i] > 0)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Value {0} was entered {1} time(s)..", i, values[i]);
   }
}
```

This is most likely what your professor is looking for.  I have not tested the code above, that's your job :)

Answer (score 0):

This code makes everything you need:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            //input data
            int[] inputArray = new int[5];
            int enteredCount = 0;
            string enteredLine = string.Empty;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers from 0 to 10. If you want to end please enter nothing");
            //while user input something not blank
            while ((enteredLine = Console.ReadLine()) != string.Empty)
            {
                //inputArray has no more elements, resize it
                if (enteredCount == inputArray.Length)
                {
                    Array.Resize<int>(ref inputArray, inputArray.Length + 5);
                }

                //new entered value to array
                inputArray[enteredCount] = int.Parse(enteredLine);
                enteredCount++;
            }

            //now we need count all uniq elements
            //special array. Index is a number from 0 to 10. Value is a count of that value
            int[] counts = new int[11];
            for (int i = 0; i < enteredCount; i++)
            {
                int enteredNumber = inputArray[i];
                counts[enteredNumber]++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Totally were entered {0} numbers", enteredCount);

            //now we now count of each number from 0 to 11. Let' print them
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                //Print only numbers, that we entered at least once
                if (counts[i] != 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Number {0} were entered {1} times", i, counts[i]);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explinations in each line! that really helped me to see the purpose and reason for being of each segment. it would have been like having been just given the answere with no explination or information as to why its right. Much thanks for the info.

Comment: @JoeFredy: Look again at pst's hint and Mike's help!

Comment: I did, they are both exactly what I was looking for.
They helped with the what and the how.
while @igofed helped with the what and the why.
I changed a few things in igofed's code to my own liking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

Then

```
Console.WriteLine("Distinct values entered & No. of times values entered:");

int[] distinctvalues = ScoreArray.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray(); 
//Finds distinct values and orders them in ascending order.

int[] distinctcount = ScoreArray.FindAllIndexof(distinctvalues).ToArray();
//Finds how many times distinct values are entered.

for (int i = 0; i < distinctvalues.Length; i++)
   Console.WriteLine(distinctvalues[i].ToString() + " --------- Entered " + 
   distinctcount[i].ToString() + " times");

Console.Read();
```

For `FindAllIndexof` function create an `Extension Method` in a `static class` outside your `Program` Class

```
public static class EM
{
    public static int[] FindAllIndexof<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, T[] val)
    {
        List<int> index = new List<int>();
        for (int j = 0; j < val.Length; j++)
            index.Add(values.Count(x => object.Equals(x, val[j])));
        return index.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Output

[image]